# Edit or change a compiled python script (.exe file) details

Tags: python, python-3.x, metadata, executable

My question is: Is there a way to easily set the details/metadata of a .exe file?

I have created a working python program that I have compiled into a .exe file using pyinstaller. 
When I go and right click the compiled program and go to Properties > Details it looks like this:

Script.exe

```
--Description-------------------
File Description
Type          Application
File Version
Product Name
Product Version
Copyright
Size          37.0 MB
Date Modified  xx/xx/2020
Language
```

I would like to be able to change this metadata.

It would be best if their is a way to do this so that all I have to do is add another file that automatically sets this data.

The closest thing that I have found that does this would be a Resouces.rc file that is used in projects that are made in C++ or C#.

Is there a way that I can fix this?
How do you do it?

Comment: You set the metadata in the `.spec` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved.

All that I had to do was create this `version.txt` and fill in the relevant information.

version.txt:

```
# UTF-8
#
# For more details about fixed file info 'ffi' see:
# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646997.aspx
VSVersionInfo(
  ffi=FixedFileInfo(
    # filevers and prodvers should be always a tuple with four items: (1, 2, 3, 4)
    # Set not needed items to zero 0.
    filevers=(x, x, x, x), #<- Put File version here
    # prodvers=(3, 0, 10, 2),
    # Contains a bitmask that specifies the valid bits 'flags'
    mask=0x3f, #<- Do not change
    # Contains a bitmask that specifies the Boolean attributes of the file.
    flags=0x0, #<- Do not change
    # The operating system for which this file was designed.
    # 0x4 - NT and there is no need to change it.
    OS=0x4, #<- Do not change
    # The general type of file.
    # 0x1 - the file is an application.
    fileType=0x1, #<- Do not change
    # The function of the file.
    # 0x0 - the function is not defined for this fileType
    subtype=0x0, #<- Do not change
    # Creation date and time stamp. Sets it automatically. Do not change.
    date=(0, 0) #<- Do not change
    ),
  kids=[ 
    StringFileInfo( 
      [ 
      StringTable(
        u'040904b0',
        [StringStruct(u'CompanyName', u'Your name here'),
        StringStruct(u'ProductName', u'name here'),
        StringStruct(u'ProductVersion', u'x.x.x.x'), #<- should be same as filevers
        StringStruct(u'OriginalFilename', u'productname.exe'),
        StringStruct(u'FileDescription', u'Short description goes here'),
        StringStruct(u'LegalCopyright', u'copyright stuff here'),
        StringStruct(u'LegalTrademarks', u'legal stuff here'),])
      ]),
    VarFileInfo([VarStruct(u'Translation', [1033, 1200])])
  ]
)
```

Once that was created, I could add it to my Pyinstaller creation command with `--version-file version.txt`